# Upper bounds for $\mathbb E[X | X+Y = z]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose that you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, of unknown distribution and that are not independent but uncorrelated. Both $X$ and $Y$ have zero expectation.

I am looking for upper bounds or statements about
$$
\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,X+Y=z].
$$

The case for Gaussianity is addressed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/signal-extraction-problem-conditional-expectation-of-one-item-in-sum-of-indepen).

Thanks!

Comment: if $f$ is the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ (the two being not independent)
$$\mathbb{E}(X | X+Y=z) = \frac{1}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,z-x) dx} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x,z-x) dx$$